# data in alert box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to populate data in alert box on button click but when I click on button then alert box not populate

I try this

```
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <button id="submitchart" runat="server">Show Chart</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submitchart').click(function() {
    //alert("i");        
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      //url: 'WebForm1.aspx / Jqufunc',
      //data: JSON.stringify({ yearP: $('#yearValue').val() }),
      //data:{},
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
        alert("i");
      }

    });
  });
  //});
</script>
```

when I write alert("i") after this line  `$('#submitchart').click(function () {` then alert box populate but when i write alert ("i") after the  `success: function() {` then alert box not populate

any solution?

Comment: that means the ajax is not a success add error function so you will. check the dev tools in XHR for ajax response..check console for error

Comment: why you have not set url in ajax???

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: how to check console errors?

Comment: check my updated question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give button type as button.

```
<head runat="server">
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <button id="submitchart" type="button" runat="server">Show Chart</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#submitchart').click(function() {
        //alert("i");        
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'WebForm1.aspx / Jqufunc',
          data: JSON.stringify({ yearP: $('#yearValue').val() }),
          //data:{},
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function() {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
            alert("i");
          }

        });
      });
      //});
    </script>
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: check this my another question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563080/data-in-alert-box-through-function-javascript?noredirect=1#comment62613784_37563080

Comment: i use function but still alert box not display

Comment: the problem is button type. by default button will work as submit button. if you click submit what ll happen. it will reload to given url. if url is not there then reload with in same page.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(function () {
            $("#submitchart").on("click", function () {
                debugger;
                alert("i");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    //url: 'WebForm1.aspx / Jqufunc',
                    //data: JSON.stringify({ yearP: $('#yearValue').val() }),
                    //data:{},
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
                        debugger;
                        alert("i");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        debugger;
                        alert("i");
                    }

                });
```

ajax will be run error,don't run success

Comment: why we write debugger?

Answer (score 0):

This happening because when you write `alert("i")` after `$('#submitchart').click(function () {` then its not dependent on success of any ajax call and ot works fine as it should but when you write this after `success: function() {` then it is dependent on ajax call and if there is some errors in ajax it will not run as you have only defined it for successful ajax.

Write this if ajax contains errors also

```
$('#submitchart').click(function() {
    //alert("i");        
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      //url: 'WebForm1.aspx / Jqufunc',
      //data: JSON.stringify({ yearP: $('#yearValue').val() }),
      //data:{},
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
        alert("i");
      },
      error: function() {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
        alert("i");
      }

    });
  });
```