# data in alert box through function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With reference of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561223/data-in-alert-box-using-javascript#comment62613199_37561223), this is how solved this without a function. 
Now I have a function and I try to call in javascript and also try to call that data in `alert` box but the `alert` box does not populate. My code is this:

```js
$('#submitchart').click(function() {
  //alert("i");
  var webmethod = 'WebForm1.aspx/Jqufunc';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: webmethod,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      yearP: $('#yearValue').val()
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      debugger;
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));
      var data1 = response.d.split('*')[0];
      var data2 = response.d.split('*')[1];
      alert(data1);
      alert(data2);
    },
    error: function() {
      debugger;
      alert(data1);
      alert(data2);
    }
  });
});

function Loadchart() {
  $('#submitchart').click();
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="yearValue" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList>
  <button id="submitchart" runat="server">Show Chart</button>
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is browser halting at debugger?

Comment: remove JSON.stringify

Comment: can you provide the format of the response?

Comment: i mean the json resulting from the ajax call

Comment: actually i am new in this java script and json ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <select id="yearValue"><option>1920</option></select>
        <button id="submitchart" runat="server" type="button">Show  Chart</button>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitchart').click(function () {
        //alert("i");
        var webmethod = 'test.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: webmethod ,
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                yearP: $('#yearValue').val() 
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert('working');

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }    
        });
    });

    function Loadchart() {
        $('#submitchart').click();
    };
</script>
```

Above code is working. Check and update with yours. Make sure button type button.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a document ready statement,remove JSON.stringify

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <select id="yearValue"><option>1920</option></select>
        <button id="submitchart" runat="server" type="button">Show  Chart</button>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#submitchart').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var webmethod = 'test.php';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: webmethod ,
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                yearP: $('#yearValue').val() 
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert('working');

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }    
        });
    }).trigger('click');
 });
</script>
```